# Objective C - Switch statement with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

What is the problem here? Why can't I use 'switch'?

```
NSString *input;
gets(charInput);
input=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:charInput];
switch (input) { //Statement requires expression of integer type ('NSString *__strong' invalid)
        case "test": //Expression is not an integer constant expression
            NSLog(@"Yes it is");
            break;
        case "Hello": //Expression is not an integer constant expression
            NSLog(@"Hey There!");
        default:
            break;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an answer about what you can and can't do (because that's not legal Objective-C) or about why the language was written that way (which might be a bit off-topic for SO)?

Comment: input=[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:charInput]integervalue];  it's solve your problem

Comment: It's exactly the same "restriction" as in C, and you should know C pretty well before you attempt to use Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective C,

Switch statement can only have **int** parameter to pass.

That's why you are getting this error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is because, errr, the "switch" statement *requires expression of integer type*.   It only allows you to use numbers.

Actually, this restriction only exists in Objective-C.  If you use SWIFT, you *can* use strings, as shown on this page:

[Swift highlights](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73997/swift-language-highlights)

(Scroll down to the "Switch statements" section.)

Comment: You're able to use strings in switch cases in Java too. Seems its only a limitation on Objective-C

Comment: (I meant, it's only an iOS restriction in Objective-C... which is what Yahllilevy is developing on.  Yes, I know alternatives are available in Java, C#, etc...)

Comment: I assume the same restriction applies on OSX, not so? (Under the same language of course )